# What is a plane symmetry?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetry

Gallian states : "a plane symmetry of a figure F in a plane is a function from the plane to itself that carries F onto F and preserves distances; that is for any points p and q in the plane, the distance from the image of p to the image of q is the same as the distance from p to q."

Now practically speaking, by 'preserving distances' do we mean not causing any deformation to the figure? And does 'carrying F onto F' mean that the region which the figure F occupied before the motion has to be the same after the motion? Is this correct? And is there anything else that is required?

I said motion because I was trying to think of it practically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now practically speaking, by 'preserving distances' do we mean not causing any deformation to the figure?

I would say that "not causing deformation" is a lot more vague than "preserves distances." You may or may not feel that scaling the plane with the transformation $x\mapsto 2x$ causes any *deformation* in the sense of changing shapes, but it does affect the size of the image. The same could be said for a reflection... it's just not clear what "deformation" means.

By stating that it preserves distances, we know that it is made up of rotations, reflections, and translations.

> And does 'carrying F onto F' mean that the region which the figure F occupied before the motion has to be the same after the motion?

It means that every point of $F$ is mapped to a point of $F$, and that every point of $F$ has some point of $F$ mapping to it. I think that's what you're saying, probably.

Comment: Yes, I did consider it as deformation. And secondly, the second criterion is only concerned about the region that is occupied before and after the motion, and the fact that they have to be the same, is that true?

Comment: @HritRoy Yes, that is what my last paragraph says.

Comment: Suppose that the figure is $F$ in a plane $P$, then a surjective function $g: P\to F$ such that $g$ preserves distances is called plane symmetry of $F$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Koro if it preserves distances, it would be a 1-1 isometry, and I’ve never heard of a figure that is isometric to a plane.  Sounds like you are overcomplicating the definition.

Comment: Actually, I am confused. Gallian states that "...". I am just putting that in symbols. I don't understand the definition as it is given by Gallian. I'll be very grateful if you could please explain that to me. Thanks.

Comment: @Koro It would make sense if it said "a distance preserving function $g:P\to P$ is a symmetry of $F$ if $g$ restricted to $F$ is a surjection $g:F\to F$"

Comment: @Koro obviously there's lots of ways to surjectively map the real plane onto the unit circle, but none of them is distance preserving, so it seems like the definition as proposed before says there aren't any symmetries of the circle.

Comment: Thanks a lot  . I understand the definition of plane symmetry now in the way given by Gallian. +1